# Click on a div with pointer-events none

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, ads, adsense

I am building  a game which uses Banner Ads. The game content itself is rendered on a canvas, taking up the full width & height.

Now the problem occurs when I am trying to place banner ads on top of the canvas. When I did this initially, the ad was fine, but when I tried to interact with the underlying game canvas, it just wouldn't focus or click due to the ad on top.

Then, I discovered the pointer events CSS rule, and I set it to none for my Ad element. Now the game works as expected, but I can't click on the ad.

One of my ideas to resolve this is to use Javascript mousemove and click events to trigger a click on the ad if the user clicks it. But I'm not sure if this the right way to accomplish this, and even if it is, how would I implement something like this

Comment: Why do they have to overlap?  How can you click on both the add and the game - wouldn't that be annoying as you try to play the game but are taken off to the add site?

Comment: Sorry I could've explained this better, but the canvas isn't just the game. The UI is rendered on there as well, and my plan is to have ads near the UI elements, and to hide the ad once the user boots into the game.

Comment: This sounds more like you need a better state management. As long as ad is shown, the user shouldn't click on the game. When the game is loaded, remove the ad. If you show/hide these elements, you don#t need any pointer-events: none stuff.

Comment: No no, say I have a banner ad right below the "Play" button of the game. The buttons,text,everything are rendered on the canvas.